# Manipulating Excel spreadsheet, removing rows based on values in a column and then removing more rows based on values in another column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a rather complicated problem.

I have a log file that when put into excel the column "I" contains event IDs, and the column J contains a custom key that keeps a particular even grouped.

All i want to do is remove any rows that do not contain the value of say 102 in the event id column. 
And THEN i need to check the custom key (column J) and remove rows that are duplicates since any duplicates will falsely show other statistics i want.

I have gotten as far as being able to retrieve the values from the columns using com objects and .entirecolumn cell value etc, but I am completely stumped as to how i can piece together a solid way to remove rows. I could not figure out how to get the row for each value.

To give a bit more clarity this is my thought process on what i need to do:

If cell value in Column I does not = 102 Then delete the row that cell contains.
Repeat for all rows in spreadsheet. 
And THEN-
Read every cell in column J and remove all rows containing duplicates based on the values in column J. 
Save spreadsheet.

Can any kind persons help me?

---

---

Additional Info:

Column I holds a string that is an event id number e.g = 1029
Column J holds a string that is a mix of numbers and letters = 1ASER0X3NEX0S

Comment: Firstly, you have completely irrelevant tags on this question - what do [tag:mysql] and [tag:vba] have to do with this? Second, you need to show us what you have tried yourself so far, and what isn't working. Finally this statement _"The details are not too important..."_ this should never be assumed when asking a question that you do not know the answer to. Have a look at how to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Okay give me a moment.

Comment: Thanks Macro man, I'll have a look and learn from the link.

Comment: Just to clarify, my comment wasn't intended to be an "ear-bashing", just to highlight that as it currently stands it isn't entirely clear what you are asking. For example I would have attempted to answer this with a [tag:powershell] script because of the title and your mention of 'COM objects' but it appears that you want a [tag:vba] solution instead. StackOverflow gets it success from the people that volunteer their time - so if you can help them to help you - it makes the world a better place :)

Comment: I initially though you were a grumpy man but on reflection my question would be extremely vague and frustrating for anyone trying to help :( 
Thanks for the help and taking the time!

Comment: I'm grumpy in real life :) - But no worries. The other (less important) thing with tags is that they drive the [syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work) for the Q&A on the page. In this case I've edited the answers to 'force' the correct highlighting as they were defaulting to [tag:powershell]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ellz, I do agree with Macro Man in that your tags are misleading and, more importantly, I did indeed need to know the details of Column J.

However, I got so sick of rude posts today and yours was polite and respectful so I've pasted some code below that will do the trick ... provided Column J can be a string (the details of which you haven't given us ... see what Macro Man's getting at?).

There are many ways to test for duplicates. One is to try and add a unique key to a collection and see if it throws an error. Many wouldn't like that philosophy but it seemed to be okay for you because it also gives you a collection of all the unique (ie remaining) keys in Column J.

```
Sub Delete102sAndDuplicates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim uniques As Collection
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rowPair As Range
    Dim iCell As Range
    Dim jCell As Range
    Dim delRows As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("I:J"))
    Set uniques = New Collection

    For Each rowPair In rng.Rows

        Set iCell = rowPair.Cells(, 1)
        Set jCell = rowPair.Cells(, 2)

        On Error Resume Next
        uniques.Add jCell.Value2, jCell.Text

        If Err = 457 Or iCell.Value2 = 102 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            If delRows Is Nothing Then
                Set delRows = rowPair.EntireRow
            Else
                Set delRows = Union(delRows, rowPair.EntireRow)
            End If
        End If

    Next

    If Not delRows is Nothing then
        MsgBox delRows.Address(False, False) & " deleted."
        delRows.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want Ambie.

Thank you so much! 

The values in J are indeed a string e.g 1918ERACSD7362

I just needed to see how someone could do it, so i can learn how it works and patch it together thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways in which this can be done, and which is best will depend on how frequently you perform this task and whether you want to have it fully automated. Since you've tagged your question with `VBA` I assume you'll be happy with a VBA-based answer:

```
Sub removeValues()

Range("I1").Select  'Start at the top of the I column
'We are going to go down the column until we hit an empty row
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) = True
    If ActiveCell.Value <> 102 Then
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete 'Then delete the row
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select 'Select the cell below
    End If
Loop

'Now we have removed all non-102 values from the column, let`s remove the duplicates from the J column
Range("A:J").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=10, Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```

The key line there is `Range("A:J").RemoveDuplicates`. It will remove rows from the range you specify according to duplicates it finds in the column you specify. In that case, it will remove items from the A-J columns based on duplicates in column 10 (which is J). If your data extends beyond the `J` column, then you'll need to replace `"A:J"` with the appropriate range. Note that the `Columns` value is relative to the index of the first column, so while the `J` column is `10` when that range starts at A (1), it would be `2` for example if the range were only `I:J`. Does that make sense?

(Note: Using `ActiveCell` is not really best practice, but it's the method that most obviously translates to what you were trying to do and as it seems you're new to VBA I thought it would be the easiest to understand).

Comment: VBA was welcomed as well thanks, I was more interested in how people do it so i could learn the code and then patch it together myself to cater to my needs.

Comment: I'd like to give extra thanks for taking the time to explain it to me as well It's very much appreciated!